# Neat way of calling InvokeRequired and Invoke

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, user-interface

I seem to remember seeing some neat way of calling InvokeRequired and Invoke to avoid repeating too much code in every event handler but I can't remember what that was.
So does anyone know a neat way of writing that code?

Preferably for VB.Net 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367718/c-automating-the-invokerequired-code-pattern) addresses this issue from a C# perspective, and any of the answers can probably be tailored to VB easily enough.

Although my answer wasn't the accepted one, I find using `MethodInvoker` anonymous method approach to be the most straightforward.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I was thinking of, though since VB2005 don't support anonymous methods I can't use it for this project.

Answer (score 1):

One way to streamline it is to use the method described in [Roy Osherove's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2007/05.aspx?PageIndex=2) (keep in mind it requires using a custom DLL):

```
[RunInUIThread]
protected virtual void DoSomeUIStuff()
{
  this.Text = "hey";
}
```

Comment: For now I'm really looking for something without any external dependencies, but an interesting option, so thanks.