# C# - Updating GUI using non-main Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface

I have a program that has Classes

- GUI
- Upload
- and a buffer between the 2 classes - ie used to communicate between the 2 classes .

The `Upload` class uses `Process` to run an command line FTP app.  I want to return what output produced by the FTP app to be displayed in a `textbox` in the GUI.
I have tried using the following code that has been truncated.

Upload Class (beginProcess() is a method used to start the Thread (not shown here)):

```
public delegate void WputOutputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e);
class Upload
{
    private WputOutputHandler wputOutput;

    beginProcess()
    {
        Process pr = new Process();                                                 
        pr.StartInfo.FileName = @"wput.exe";                                        
        pr.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        pr.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        pr.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        pr.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OnDataReceived);
        pr.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OnDataReceived);
        pr.Start();                                                                 
        pr.BeginOutputReadLine();
        pr.WaitForExit();
    }


    public void OnDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(wputOutput != null)
        {
            wputOutput(sender, e);
        }
    }


    public event WputOutputHandler WputOutput
    {
        add
        {
            wputOutput += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            wputOutput -= value;
        }
    }
}
```

Buffer Class:

```
public void EventSubscriber()
{
    uploadSession.WputOutput += Main.writeToTextBoxEvent;
}
```

Main Class:

```
public void writeToTextBoxEvent(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if(this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        MethodInvoker what now?
    }
    else
    {
        textBox1.Text = e.Data;
    }
}
```

As you can see, when it come to the Main method's writeToTextBoxEvent, I've ran out of ideas.  I'm not sure whether doing a UI update using a custom event is even the best way to do it.  If someone could point me in the right direction I would be most grateful.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c?rq=1 too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
public void writeToTextBoxEvent(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if(this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        // In .Net 2.0
        this.textBox1.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => writeToTextBoxEvent(sender, e)));

        // In .Net 3.5 (above is also possible, but looks nicer)
        this.textBox1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => writeToTextBoxEvent(sender, e)));
    }
    else
    {
        textBox1.Text = e.Data;
    }
}
```

The advantage for this method against Richard solution is you don't need to write the executing code twice (within the `BeginInvoke()` and again in the `else` path).

#### Update

If you're on .Net 3.5 make it as an extension method:

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static void SafeInvoke(this Control control, Action action)
    {
        if (control.InvokeRequired)
        {
            control.Invoke(action);
        }
        else
        {
            action();
        }
    }

    public static void SafeBeginInvoke(this Control control, Action action)
    {
        if (control.InvokeRequired)
        {
            control.BeginInvoke(action);
        }
        else
        {
            action();
        }
    }
}
```

And use it that way:

```
public void writeToTextBoxEvent(object sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // Write it as a single line
    this.textBox1.SafeBeginInvoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text = e.Data));

    this.textBox1.SafeBeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            //Write it with multiple lines
            textBox1.Text = e.Data;
        }));
}
```

Comment: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: @johnnyturbo3 see my update to my answer: type inference fails in this case, just create an `Action` instance and pass that.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
{
   Action a = () => { textBox1.Text = e.Data; };
  textBox1.Invoke(a);
}
```

I.e. use a delegate (which can be a closure to capture local variables) with the [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) method. This will dispatch the delegate to be executed on the textbox's thread. `Invoke` will return when the delegate has completed execution.

There is also an asynchronous version when you don't need to wait ([`BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx)).

EDIT: Forgot that because `Invoke` takes a `Delegate` type inference fails, so use local. **NB** you can of course create the delegate at an earlier point and use it in both branches to avoid duplicate code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a popular extension mechanism:

```
public static void InvokeIfRequired(this System.Windows.Forms.Control c,
                                    Action action) {
    if (c.InvokeRequired) {
        c.Invoke((Action)(() => action()));
    }
    else {
        action();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public void writeToTextBoxEvent(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) {
    this.textBox1.InvokeIfRequired(() => { textBox1.Text = e.Data; }
}
```

Comment: Tsk, tsk, attribution required here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367718/c-automating-the-invokerequired-code-pattern/2367763#2367763

Comment: Thanks Hans! I understand, but I'm not sure if that source is the original one. There are hundreds of similar example. :) But yes, that answer is pretty same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a responsive UI, you need a worker thread and the main thread to update the UI.

I think you need a worker thread to look for data being received and then from your worker thread use a delegate to write data to your TextBox.

Something like :

```
public delegate void textBoxWriteDelegate(string msg);

private void textBoxWrite(string sMess) {
  textBox.AppendText(sMess);
}
```

And from your worker thread :

```
Invoke(new textBoxWriteDelegate(textBoxWrite), new object [] { "Launching ftp cmd line .... \n" });
```

Sorry it's net 1.1  ;) There's a better way to write delegates in 2.0 and higher...

Answer (score 0):

I created a little helper for that:

```
class LayoutsEngine 
{
    internal static void ThreadSafeDoer(Form Form, Delegate Whattodo)
    {
        if (!Form.IsDisposed)
        {
            if (Form.InvokeRequired)
            {
                Form.Invoke(Whattodo);
            }
            else
            {
                Whattodo.DynamicInvoke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and am using it like this:

```
    LayoutsEngine.ThreadSafeDoer(this, new MethodInvoker(delegate()
    {
         txtWhatever.Text=whatever();
         //  and any other GUI meddling
    }));
```

Also, if anyone has a way to reduce `MethodInvoker()` here, please comment.

Comment: Nope, not possible. You can only replace it in 3.5 by the nicer one `Action`.