# Convert Console.WriteLine into textbox

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
Console.WriteLine("Network adapter: {0}", adapters[i].Name);
                Console.WriteLine("    Status:            {0}", adapters[i].OperationalStatus.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("    Interface:         {0}", adapters[i].NetworkInterfaceType.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("    Description:       {0}", adapters[i].Description);
                Console.WriteLine("    ID:                {0}", adapters[i].Id);
                Console.WriteLine("    Speed:             {0}", adapters[i].Speed);
                Console.WriteLine("    SupportsMulticast: {0}", adapters[i].SupportsMulticast);
                Console.WriteLine("    IsReceiveOnly:     {0}", adapters[i].IsReceiveOnly);
                Console.WriteLine("    MAC:               {0}", adapters[i].GetPhysicalAddress().ToString());
```

What I want is to have this Console.WriteLine displayed in a text box on the form but don't have any idea on how to do it.

Comment: Do you want to pipe an existing console application into a TextBox or convert the above to write to populate a TextBox

Comment: @bryanbcook: Hi! sir. yes I want to convert it.

Answer (score 4):

If like me you didn't like the StringBuilder solution check out Sébastien's blog

[How to redirect the Console’s output to a TextBox in C#](http://saezndaree.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/how-to-redirect-the-consoles-output-to-a-textbox-in-c/)

Comment: Definitly the way to go! With this approach you don't even  need to replace your `Console.WriteLine statements`.

Answer (score 3):

Just make sure that the text box is set to multiline:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Network adapter: {0}", adapters[i].Name));
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("    Status:            {0}", adapters[i].OperationalStatus.ToString()));
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("    Interface:         {0}", adapters[i].NetworkInterfaceType.ToString()));
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("    Description:       {0}", adapters[i].Description));
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("    ID:                {0}", adapters[i].Id));
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("    Speed:             {0}", adapters[i].Speed));
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("    SupportsMulticast: {0}", adapters[i].SupportsMulticast));
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("    IsReceiveOnly:     {0}", adapters[i].IsReceiveOnly));
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("    MAC:               {0}", adapters[i].GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()));

textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try reading current process' `stdout` for example from here:
     `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().StandardOutput`

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to pipe an existing console application into a TextBox, here's something similar where I piped content from a process into a console.  http://www.bryancook.net/2008/03/redirect-standard-output-of-service-to.html

The difference between that example and what you'd want to do is change the logging to push the data into the Textbox.

But beware! You can only append output to a TextBox from the thread that it was created on (the UI thread).  You'll need to marshal the data from the other thread to the UI thread.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367718/c-automating-the-invokerequired-code-pattern) which has a great extension method to push data to the UI.

You'd end up with:

```
private static void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
    {
       _textBox.InvokeIfRequired( c => c.Text += e.Data );       
    }
}
```