# How to Invoke the progress bar in Status strip?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am using the following code to invoke the controls that are on the main UI thread in my application. The progress bar that I have in my Status Strip does not have a InvokeRequired, I need to somehow invoke the System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripProgressBar.

```
if (txtbox1.InvokeRequired)
{
txtbox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { txtbox1.Text = string.Empty; }));
}
```

Comment: @Sev: If you are using System.Windows.Forms.Controls.ProgressBar then it contains InvokeRequeired method, because it is derived from Control and Control implements ISynchronizeInvoke interface.

Comment: I am using System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripProgressBar

Comment: can I use a backgroundWorker just for this single control? I dont wanna redo the whole Threading codes

Comment: @Sev: it is not a Control. did you try using it and find any problems in multithread with it?

Comment: it does not have a InvokeRequired, all other controls have InvokeRequired

Comment: @Sev: The `System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripProgressBar` is not inherited from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`, so it is not a control. the question is did you find any troubles when using it at multithreading application?

Comment: yes,
Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on. 
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(Int32 msg, Int32 wparam, Int32 lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar.UpdatePos()
   at System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar.set_Value(Int32 value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripProgressBar.set_Value(Int32 value)

Comment: @Sev: then use `this.InvokeRequired` because the `ToolStripProgressBar` and all other controls created in the form are created and initialized at the same form thread.

Comment: this.InvokeRequired did not work, I tried the toolstrip.InvokeRequired too but no luck.

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripProgressBarprgBarMain.GetCurrentParent().InvokeRequired     is the solution in case someone needed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
if (toolStripProgressBar1.Parent.InvokeRequired)
{
    toolStripProgressBar1.Parent.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { toolStripProgressBar1.Value= 100; }));
}
```

Comment: Thank you but There is no Parent. instead I did this
    prgBarMain.GetCurrentParent().InvokeRequired

Comment: `Parent` is listed under Properties for `ToolStringProgressBar` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripprogressbar.aspx . Not sure why you don't have it.

Comment: Parent property is internal for .net 4.5

Answer (score 3):

Try dropping in this handy extension method:

```
public static class ControlEx
{
    public static void Invoke(this System.Windows.Forms.Control @this, Action action)
    {
        if (@this == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("@this");
        if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
        if (@this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            @this.Invoke(action);
        }
        else
        {
            action();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can just do this:

```
txtbox1.Invoke(() => toolStripProgressBar1.Value = value);
```

It safely calls the action on the UI thread and can be called from any actual control.

Comment: pitty you didnt answer the question, lets see a example using the progress bar as requested.

Comment: @scott - The example using the process bar is right there in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try invoking the ToolStrip and not the ToolStripProgressBar:

```
    delegate void ToolStripPrograssDelegate(int value);
    private void ToolStripPrograss(int value)
    {
        if (toolStrip1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            ToolStripPrograssDelegate del = new ToolStripPrograssDelegate(ToolStripPrograss);
            toolStrip1.Invoke(del, new object[] { value });
        }
        else
        {
            toolStripProgressBar1.Value = value; // Your thingy with the progress bar..
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure it will work, but give it a shoot.

If this wont work try this:

```
    delegate void ToolStripPrograssDelegate(int value);
    private void ToolStripPrograss(int value)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            ToolStripPrograssDelegate del = new ToolStripPrograssDelegate(ToolStripPrograss);
            this.Invoke(del, new object[] { value });
        }
        else
        {
            toolStripProgressBar1.Value = value; // Your thingy with the progress bar..
        }
    }
```

'this' should be the Form it's self.

Comment: I am adding the steps to progressbar in the following method. How can I use your code here?

    public void AddProgressBarValue(int _step)
    {
    prgBarMain.Value += _step;
    }

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the generic invoker from [Automating the InvokeRequired code pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367718/automating-the-invokerequired-code-pattern) designed to invoke any *Control*:

```
//Neat generic trick to invoke anything on a windows form control class  
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367718/automating-the-invokerequired-code-pattern
//Use like this:
//object1.InvokeIfRequired(c => { c.Visible = true; });
//object1.InvokeIfRequired(c => { c.Text = "ABC"; });
//object1.InvokeIfRequired(c => 
//  { 
//      c.Text = "ABC";
//      c.Visible = true; 
//  }
//);
public static void InvokeIfRequired<T>(this T c, Action<T> action) where T : Control
{
    if (c.InvokeRequired)
    {
        c.Invoke(new Action(() => action(c)));
    }
    else
    {
        action(c);
    }
}
```

Objects in the ToolStrip are *ToolStripItem* and have no InvokeRequired. But the parent has and the above can be rewritten to use the parent .Invoke():

```
public static void InvokeIfRequiredToolstrip<T>(this T c, Action<T> action) where T : ToolStripItem
{
    if (c.GetCurrentParent().InvokeRequired)
    {
        c.GetCurrentParent().Invoke(new Action(() => action(c)));
    }
    else
    {
        action(c);
    }
}
```