# Modify Label Form From Another Class Thread

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I Use a thread to send an email. 
I need write text in a label to let user know when email was send in a form of budgets.

' Option Strict is off

Function on class form.

```
Public Sub ChangeLblText(ByVal msg As String) ' LblIconos.modifiers = public (In form)
     lblIconos.Text = msg
End Sub
```

Declarated class of new thread. (Global declared.)

```
Public TasksPresu As New TasksClassPresu()
```

An Icon of Form "Presupuestos" trigger the thread

```
    Dim Thread1 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf TasksPresu.TaskEmail)
    Thread1.Start()
```

Class Trigged thread

```
Public Class TasksClassPresu
    Sub TaskEmail()
    'trigger label change?
     Presupuestos.ChangeLblText("Test")
    end sub
End Class
```

I tried Invoke metods, delegate functions and adress of form without work, may be i left something.

An example delegate that i used:

---

In Form Presupuestos class:

```
Public Delegate Sub LabelDelegate(ByVal Msg As String)
```

In Global Module to declare most of variables

```
 Public Llamada As Presupuestos.LabelDelegate
```

Function on class form.

```
Public Sub ChangeLblText(ByVal msg As String) ' LblIconos.modifiers = public (In form)
     lblIconos.Text = msg
End Sub
```

Class Trigger

```
Public Class TasksClassPresu
    Sub TaskEmail()
        Llamada.Invoke("prueba")
    End Sub
End Class
```

When run this make an error in this line: lbliconos.text = msg
Error: "Illegal operation through threads. It had access to the control "lbliconos" from a thread other than that which was created"

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the details in front of me, but you need to check `lblIconos.InvokeRequired` in `ChangeLblText` and `Invoke` a delegate call itself when true.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2367718/256431), and [many others like it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=InvokeRequired), gives more details.