# Updating GUI from other thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm trying to update a listbox from another thread, what is the simplest way to achieve this?

I tried Invoking the textbox, but it didn't work.

```
private void dowork()
{
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    client.Connect("192.168.1.3", 10);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());

    JObject o = new JObject();
    o.Add("comando", 1);
    o.Add("dir", @"C:\Users\klein\Desktop\Acionamentos");
    writer.Write(o.ToString());
    writer.Flush();
    JArray array = JArray.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(array[i]);  //update GUI from this thread
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(dowork);
    t.Start();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367718/c-automating-the-invokerequired-code-pattern (possible duplicate)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `BackgroundWorker`, you can do your async stuff in `DoWork`, report your progress using `bgworker.ReportProgress()` and you will get the callback in `ProgressChanged` (I would call ReportProgress for every element processed), then you will be able to update your GUI controls.

The worker can also fire `RunWorkerCompleted` when it ends.

```
YourType arrayitem;

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    client.Connect("192.168.1.3", 10);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());

    JObject o = new JObject();
    o.Add("comando", 1);
    o.Add("dir", @"C:\Users\klein\Desktop\Acionamentos");
    writer.Write(o.ToString());
    writer.Flush();
    JArray array = JArray.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());

    int percentage;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
    {
        arrayitem = array[i];
        percentage = ((i + 1)*100)/array.Count;
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percentage);
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(arrayitem);
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage; // in case you'd want to add a progressbar
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "Done";
}
```

Keep in mind your backgroundworker must have true in the `WorkerReportProgress` property.

Comment: Do you have any examples on this approach?

Comment: I added one example, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Control.Invoke` to get on UI thread and then update the list box.

However, I suggest you look at using a `BackgroundWorker`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke. You can check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx) link to have better understanding on how to update the UI controls from different thread.
For example, if the listbox is named listbox1

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
{
    listBox1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        new Action(delegate() { listBox1.Items.Add(array[i]) });
}
```