# TextBox AppendText does not work with Log4Net logs

Tags: c#, textbox, log4net, appender

I'm trying to use a `Form` with `TextBox` as an appender for `log4net` but `TextBox` simply do not append text. I see, that `AppendText` method is called (from UI thread), property `Text` is changed, but at some time appended value just dissapearing and `Text` property is still empty.

I'm not sure, if it is `log4net` issue, but the problem appears only with logs.

Application start-up and form
(`InvokeIfRequired` is very common extension from here: [Automating the InvokeRequired code pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367718/automating-the-invokerequired-code-pattern)):

```
public partial class FormMain : Form, IAppender
{
    readonly ILog log;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        Application.Run(new FormMain());
    }
    public FormMain()
    {
        log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(FormMain));

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void DoAppend(LoggingEvent le)
    {
        tbLog.AppendText("This msg is NOT shown");

        tbLog.InvokeIfRequired(() =>
            {
                // NOT SHOWN
                tbLog.AppendText(string.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.fff}> [{1}] [{2}] {3}", le.TimeStamp, le.LoggerName, le.Level, le.MessageObject));
            });
    }

    private void bTestLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tbLog.AppendText("This msg is shown");

        log.Debug("Test logs");
    }
}
```

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender,log4net">
      <file value="mylogfile.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FormMain" type="Client.FormMain,Client" />

    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="FormMain"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>

</configuration>
```

AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

After clicking the button `bTestLog` only one message appears on `tbLog`: "This msg is shown"

**UPD**
I've monitored `Text` property of `tbLog` and found it very strange. After first appending, as expected, it is "This msg is shown". But when program enters `DoAppend` method, it's empty. Further appends change it as expected, but when back to `bTestLog_Click` it's "This msg is shown" again!

Comment: Is it possible that the first `AppendText` call within `DoAppend` is generating an exception because of being on the wrong thread? If you remove that call, is the one within `InvokeIfRequired` used?

Comment: No, there is no exception. Debug=>Exceptions are all on. And I'm walking through it with Debugger, everything is OK and InvokeIfRequired is called properly

Comment: And yes, if I remove first line in `DoAppend` it still doesn't work

Comment: @JonSkeet Still not used to comment system... Now you're notified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I *think* I've got it.

I strongly suspect that this:

```
<appender name="FormMain" type="Client.FormMain,Client" />
```

... is getting log4net to create a *new* instance of `FormMain`. So you've got one instance being shown, but there's another form which isn't being shown, but is receiving append calls.

You should be able to see that in the debugger - if you put breakpoints in both `DoAppend` and `bTestLog_Click`, you'll see the instance that the methods are being invoked on being different.

I don't know the best way of hooking log4net into an *existing* object, but you may find that you can just programmatically add an appender in log4net; you should look at the API for more details.

As an aside, I'd probably separate the concerns of "being an appender" and "being a form" - I'd create an implementation of `IAppender` which appends to a text box which is provided in its constructor, and then pass the relevant text box from the form when you construct the appender. That's a slightly different matter though :)

Comment: i have a question for you.can i ask now

Comment: @PSR: Unless it's actually directly related to the original question or this answer, you should ask a separate new question.

Comment: @PSR: And you think that adding comments on *completely unrelated* answers is a good way to get attention? It really isn't. (Improve your question instead.)

Comment: i asked for the reasons .But no one is responding.I have really in confusion.can i send email to you what you specified in your profile

Comment: @PSR: I fail to see why you think that means it's okay to add comments on unrelated answers. And no, please *don't* send me an email about this. Ask a *good* question, and you won't get downvotes. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @PSR: No, I'm busy. I am *not* a personal assistant to be called on, particularly via offtopic comments. If I happen to see the question and it's good, so be it - but if I don't, I don't.