# Multi-threading -- Updating a listview in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, listview

I am trying to update my listview in a windows forms application that processes a text file updates the control. My problem is cross-threading related; whenever I try to update the control an error arises. There were no errors before I multi-threaded the application, however the UI would only update once the entire text file was processed. I would like the UI to update after each line is read.

I have posted the related code, hopefully someone can give me some tips because I am at a wall right now. The error occurs during the if statement in the UpdateListView method. Note the PingServer method is one that I have written, and is unrelated to my question.

```
    private void rfshBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string line;
        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        var file = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\nnicolini\\Documents\\Crestron\\Virtual Machine Servers\\servers.txt");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Tuple<string, string> response = PingServer(line);
            Thread updateThread = new Thread(() => { UpdateListView(line, response.Item1, response.Item2); });
            updateThread.Start();
            while (!updateThread.IsAlive) ;
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
        file.Close();
    }

    private void UpdateListView(string host, string tries, string stat)
    {
        if (!listView1.Items.ContainsKey(host)) //if server is not already in listview
        {
            var item = new ListViewItem(new[] { host, tries, stat });
            item.Name = host;
            listView1.Items.Add(item); //add it to the table
        }
        else //update the row
        {
            listView1.Items.Find(host, false).FirstOrDefault().SubItems[0].Text = host;
            listView1.Items.Find(host, false).FirstOrDefault().SubItems[1].Text = tries;
            listView1.Items.Find(host, false).FirstOrDefault().SubItems[2].Text = stat;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to check if the control is being invoked, and then call it from the underlying thread. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/12179408/752527

Comment: *Lots* of existing resources about this, if you just search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cross-thread+%5Bwinforms%5D+%5Bc%23%5D

Answer (score 1):

Winform components can be updated only from the main thread. If you want to do the update form other thread, updating code should be invoked on the main thread using `component.BeginInvoke()`.

Instead of

```
 listView1.Items.Add(item);
```

You can write something like:

```
listView1.BeginInvoke(() => listView1.Items.Add(item));
```

If your thread is doing only UI updates and nothing else resource intensive, then it is reasonable not to use it at all and call UpdateListView as a method from the main thread.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I've tried invoking in the UpdateListView method, but I had the same error.