# Cannot convert lamba expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I imported a project into Visual Studio that I wanna check out the source code from and experiment compiling it, but I get the error mentioned in about 20 different places in the same CS files.

Here's one example section of code that throws the error:  (The error is the entire overload passed to this.Invoke).

```
  if (this.InvokeRequired)
  {
    this.Invoke((Delegate) (() => this.CheckVersionInfo()));
  }
```

Comment: lots of info on this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367718/automating-the-invokerequired-code-pattern

Answer (score 4):

You can only convert from lambda expressions to *specific* delegate types. In this particular case it's really easy though - you can just use `Action` instead (or `MethodInvoker`, or any delegate type with no parameters and a `void` return type):

```
if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
  this.Invoke((Action) (() => this.CheckVersionInfo()));
}
```

Or just use a method group conversion to simplify things:

```
if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
  this.Invoke((Action)CheckVersionInfo);
}
```

Alternatively, add an extension method to `Control` or `ISynchronizeInvoke` either *just* to add an `Invoke(Action)` method, or a "check and invoke" method. (Both can be useful, in different contexts.)

To be honest though, I would be very nervous of the rest of the code you're importing if it's basically broken like this. If the code doesn't even *compile* to start with, how much confidence do you have that it will *work* once you've fixed the most obvious errors?

Note that this isn't just a matter of different versions of C# or anything like that - the code you've posted would *never* have worked, in any version of C#.

Comment: _the code you've posted would never have worked, in any version of C#_ , I was just about to ask you about that :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I try it it gives me this error: 'EUsing the generic type 'System.Action<T>' requires 1 type arguments'

Comment: Actually it seems that works if I change the .NET version to 3.5.  This project was using 2.0.

Comment: @user1653653: Oh, are you using .NET 2.0? (The non-generic `Action` class was introduced in .NET 3.5.) In that case either declare an `Action` delegate yourself or use `MethodInvoker`.) In future, if you're using a version of .NET which is that far behind the current version, please indicate that in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => this.CheckVersionInfo()));
```