# Continual Read Serial Data To Textbox

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have the following C# program with a button called *GetForceButton* and a multiline textbox called *ForceTextbox*. Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
   serialPort1 = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(components);
   serialPort1.PortName = "COM7";
   serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
   serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
   serialPort1.Open();
   serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
}

bool buttonpressed = false;

public void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
   string indata = sp.ReadLine();
   if (buttonpressed == true)
   {
      ForceTextbox.Text = indata + "\n";
   }
   else
   {
      ForceTextbox.Text = "No data received";
   }
}

private void GetForceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   buttonpressed = true;
}
```

When I step through the code, *indata* is getting the value from the serialPort of **"0.00\r"** (including the speech brackets).

After stepping to the *ForceTextbox.Text = indata + "\n";* line, an exception is being thrown up saying:

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll. Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'ForceTextbox' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.*

What does that mean, or what am I doing wrong please?

Comment: If I take out the "ForceTextbox.Text" lines and replace them with "Messagebox.Show" then the whole thing works.
Is there something wrong with the way I am calling the "ForceTextbox" to be written to???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367718/automating-the-invokerequired-code-pattern).

The long and short of it is you need to make sure that you update GUI components on the same thread that started them. Mostly, this is done by the GUI thread.

You'll be using `InvokeRequired` as shown in that link.

You have to do this in C# all over the place unfortunately.
[One other tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from Microsoft.