# how to close tcp socket connection in c#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have this tcp socket chat application from youtube

server side

```
int i;
TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1980); 
NetworkStream stream;
TcpClient client; 
byte[] datalength = new byte[4];

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void ServerReceive()
{
    stream = client.GetStream(); 
    new Thread(() => 
    {
        while ((i = stream.Read(datalength, 0, 4)) != 0)
        {

            byte[] data = new byte[BitConverter.ToInt32(datalength, 0)]; 
            stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length); 
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate 
            {
                txtLog.Text += System.Environment.NewLine + "Client : " + Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
            });
        }
    }).Start(); 

}

public void ServerSend(string msg)
{
    stream = client.GetStream(); 
    byte[] data; 
    data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(msg); 
    int length = data.Length; 
    byte[] datalength = new byte[4]; 
    datalength = BitConverter.GetBytes(length); 
    stream.Write(datalength, 0, 4); 
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); 
}

private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (client.Connected) 
        {
            ServerSend(txtSend.Text); 
        }
    }catch
    {
        txtLog.Text += "connection close";
    }
}

private void btnListen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    server.Start(); 

    new Thread(() =>
    {
        client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

        if (client.Connected)
        {
            ServerReceive();                    
        }
    }).Start();

}
```

client side

```
int i;
TcpClient client;
NetworkStream stream; 
byte[] datalength = new byte[4]; 

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void ClientReceive()
{

    stream = client.GetStream();
    new Thread(() =>
      {
          while ((i = stream.Read(datalength, 0, 4)) != 0)
          {

              byte[] data = new byte[BitConverter.ToInt32(datalength, 0)];
              stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
              this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
              {
                  txtLog.Text += System.Environment.NewLine + "Server : " + Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
              });
          }
      }).Start();

}

public void ClientSend(string msg)
{
    stream = client.GetStream(); 
    byte[] data; 
    data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(msg);
    int length = data.Length; 
    byte[] datalength = new byte[4]; 
    datalength = BitConverter.GetBytes(length);
    stream.Write(datalength, 0, 4);
    try
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
    catch
    {
        stream.Dispose();
        client.Close();
    }
}

private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 1980); 
        ClientReceive();
        txtLog.Text += Environment.NewLine+ "Connected";

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
    }
}

private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (client.Connected) 
    {
        ClientSend(txtSend.Text); 
    }
}
```

now, all of these works fine for me, however everytime i close one them i get this error
'Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.' at `ClientReceive`() or `ServerReceive`()

how should i catch this error if one of them suddenly closed or the network cable suddenly unplug? thanks in advance

Comment: With a `try..catch` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you're receiving a `System.IO.IOException` from the `NetworkStream` object.  This exception has a nested [`System.Net.Sockets.SocketException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.Sockets.SocketException%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with an [`ErrorCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketexception.errorcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of 10054 ([`SocketErrorCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketexception.socketerrorcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) == `ConnectionReset`).  To handle the exception, use a `try-catch` block.  For example,

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;

stream = client.GetStream();
new Thread(() =>
  {
      try
      {
          while ((i = stream.Read(datalength, 0, 4)) != 0)
          {
              byte[] data = new byte[BitConverter.ToInt32(datalength, 0)];
              stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
              this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
              {
                  txtLog.Text += System.Environment.NewLine + "Server : " + Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
              });
          }
      }
      catch (IOException ioex)
      {
          if (ioex.InnerException != null)
          {
              var sex = ex.InnerException as SocketException;
              if (sex == null)
              {
                  txtLog.Text += Environment.NewLine + "An unknown exception occurred.";
              }
              else
              {
                  switch (sex.SocketErrorCode)
                  {
                      case SocketError.ConnectionReset:
                          txtLog.Text += Environment.NewLine + "A ConnectionReset SocketException occurred."
                          break;
                      default:
                          txtLog.Text += Environment.NewLine + "A SocketException occurred.";
                          break;
                  }
              }
          }
          else
          {
              txtLog.Text += Environment.NewLine + "An IOException occurred.";
          }
      }
  }).Start();
```

Comment: when i started the connection and  terminated the client i got this error on the server side at ' case SocketError.ConnectionReset:
                          txtLog.Text += Environment.NewLine + "A ConnectionReset SocketException occurred.";
                          break;' Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'txtLog' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: Controls can only be accessed on the thread they are created on.  I didn't make the connection about `txtLog` being a control.  Adding to it in the anonymous thread delegate is the source of the problem.  Give me a moment to find a SO post addressing the issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367718/automating-the-invokerequired-code-pattern for making it more streamlined.

Comment: I *think* you could put the entire catch block inside a call to `txtLog.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { /* catch block here */ });` as a quick solution.

Comment: thank you for the good answer sir..for now i'd just comment out all controls in catch and study the threading later..:-)