# 'Unreachable code detected' I've looked under other unreachable codes but I can't seem to fix mine, halp

Tags: c#

I'm doing a tictactoe project for school and I can't seem to fix my unreachable code problem. I've looked up other Unreachable code issues but I'm not sure how to fix it since I'm not very good at this. I know that its a warning but when i start my program it wont fill in the blanks when i press em.

```
    private void Movement(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<object, EventArgs>(Movement), new object[] { sender, e });
            return;
            UpdateData(sender); //This is where it points for unreachable
            var lbl = (Label)sender;
            lbl.Enabled = false;
            lbl.Text = currentPlayer.ToString();
            if (!CheckWin())
                NextTurn();

        }
    }
    private void UpdateData(object sender)
        {
            Label lbl = sender as Label;
            if (lbl == lbl00)
                GameData[0, 0] = currentPlayer;
            else if (lbl == lbl10)
                GameData[1, 0] = currentPlayer;
            else if (lbl == lbl20)
                GameData[2, 0] = currentPlayer;
            else if (lbl == lbl01)
                GameData[0,1] = currentPlayer;
            else if (lbl == lbl11)
                GameData[1, 1] = currentPlayer;
            else if (lbl == lbl21)
                GameData[2, 1] = currentPlayer;
            else if (lbl == lbl02)
                GameData[0, 2] = currentPlayer;
            else if (lbl == lbl12)
                GameData[1, 2] = currentPlayer;
            else if (lbl == lbl22)
                GameData[2, 2] = currentPlayer;
        }
```

Comment: You have a `return` statement above that line, so it will always return and never do the unreachable code. What is the `return` for?

Comment: The `return` after this line `this.Invoke(new Action<object, EventArgs>(Movement), new object[] { sender, e });`will get out of the whole method, so all lines after return will not be executed.

Answer (score 5):

Because you put a `return` after `this.Invoke(new Action<object, EventArgs>(Movement), new object[] { sender, e });` line so other lines are not reachable

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the more obvious answers, you haven't implemented the ["Invoke on UI Thread"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367718/automating-the-invokerequired-code-pattern) pattern correctly. You either need to replace the return with an extra `else` branch:

```
private void Movement(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        // Oops, we're not on the UI thread. Invoke on the UI thread.
        this.Invoke(new Action<object, EventArgs>(Movement), new object[] { sender, e });
        ... nasty exceptions happen if you try and update UI controls on a non-UI thread
    }
    else
    {
        // Now we're on the UI thread
        UpdateData(sender);
        ... clear to interact with UI controls.
    }
}
```

Although you COULD also refactor the code to exit the non-UI thread branch early, using `return`, and then drop the `else`.

```
private void Movement(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        // Oops, we're not on the UI thread. Invoke on the UI thread.
        this.Invoke(new Action<object, EventArgs>(Movement), new object[] { sender, e });
        return; // i.e. exit the method here from this non UI thread branch
    }
    // We are now on the UI thread ...
    UpdateData(sender);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's the second example, i.e. OP has accidentally deleted the `}` after the return, and instead added an extra `}` after the "on UI thread" code.