# How to fix an instance when trying to access a button of another winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

hello i have this code here `(Owner as ReadBarCodeInMenu).btnContainerInquiry.Enabled = true;` it keeps me throwing an instance whenever i tried to access a button of another page it tried this code in a test 2 forms and it works perfectly fine but when i put it in system i gave me an error.Please help me

edit:

form ReadBarCodeInMenu

```
private void btnContainerInquiry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        inquiry.Owner = this;
        btnContainerInquiry.Enabled = false;
    }
```

form ContainerInquiry

```
private void logoutBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      (Owner as ReadBarCodeInMenu).btnContainerInquiry.Enabled = true; 
      error// {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
      close.      
    }
```

this is how i access the bottom of an another form if i do this in new 2 form it works with no error.

Comment: Please show your code showing the problem, we can't guess.

Comment: my error is an instance  (Owner as ReadBarCodeInMenu).btnContainerInquiry.Enabled = true; {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: Try to start debugging and step through you code. (Either 'Owner' is null or btnContainer.Inquiry is null)

Comment: Because `Owner` is probably not a `ReadBarCodeInMenu`. "Owner" is strange anyway. What do you mean by another page? You need a reference to the form containing button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you open form `ContainerInquiry` from withing form `ReadBarCodeInMenu`, you can do the following. In form `ContainerInquiry`, add a parameter to the constructor, accepting a reference to the first form

```
private ReadBarCodeInMenu _readBarCodeInMenu;

public ContainerInquiry(ReadBarCodeInMenu readBarCodeInMenu)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _readBarCodeInMenu = readBarCodeInMenu;
}

private void logoutBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _readBarCodeInMenu.btnContainerInquiry.Enabled = true; 
}
```

Also, change the accessibility of `btnContainerInquiry` from `private` to `internal` (or `public`).

---

Then in form `ReadBarCodeInMenu`

```
// Pass a reference of ReadBarCodeInMenu to ContainerInquiry.
var frm = new ContainerInquiry(this);
...
```

---

You cannot access the UI from another thread than the UI thread. If try to do so, you are getting the exception

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'btnContainerInquiry' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

In this case you must invoke the control or form you are accessing. This mechanism passes a delegate to the right thread and executes it there.

```
var btn = _readBarCodeInMenu.btnContainerInquiry;
if (btn.InvokeRequired) {
    btn.Invoke(new Action(() => btn.Enabled = true));
} else {
    btn.Enabled = true; 
}
```

You could also create an extension method that automates this process as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12179408/880990

Comment: it works but i need to access to another form in order to close it or else it give me an error of {"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'btnContainerInquiry' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."}

example if i open form 1 and click the button for form2 i can't close the form to i need to press the button for form3 in form 1 then close the form 2.