# C# Dynamically update labels

Tags: c#, automation, delegates, label, invoke

I have the following code that I use to update a label:

```cs
private delegate void DisplayDelegate(string message);

private void DisplayMessage(string message)
{
    if (label2.InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new DisplayDelegate(DisplayMessage), new object[] { message });
    }
    else
    {
        label2.Text = message;
    }
}
```

It takes in a string message and in this case updates `label2`.

In the `DisplayMessage` function is there a way to add a dynamic label option?

Something along the lines

```cs
DisplayMessage("Hello World","label1")
```

The first option being the message and the second option being the label.

If not would anyone know an alternative solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use the label as Parameter? `void DisplayMessage(string message, Label label);`

Comment: See also my [InvokeIfRequired](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12179408/880990) extension method which is reusable and simplifies invoking code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variation of the suggestion by Ralf:

```
private Action<string, Label> updateLabelDel = (s, l) => l.Text = s;

private void DisplayMessage(string message, Label label)
{
    
    if (label.InvokeRequired)
    {
        label.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { updateLabelDel(message, label); });
    }
    else
    {
        updateLabelDel(message, label);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
DisplayMessage("Hello World", label2);
```