# How do I convert this VB.NET invokerequired code to c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I inherited an old VB.NET program that was written long before I got to this job. I'm having to rewrite it in C#. I have been unable to find anything that seems to be a conversion for this. Can someone show me a translation for this in C#, please?

```
Private Sub Log(Message As String)

    Try

        If txtLog.InvokeRequired Then

            txtLog.Invoke(Sub()
                              Log(Message)
                          End Sub)
        Else
            txtLog.AppendText(Message & Environment.NewLine)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Which part are you unsure about? The lambda/anonymous sub?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automating the InvokeRequired code pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367718/automating-the-invokerequired-code-pattern)

Comment: Or use an [online code converter](https://converter.telerik.com/)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes every code converter gives an error on this.

Comment: [This one](https://converter.telerik.com/) worked for me. You have to click the button in the middle in order to have VB.NET to the left and C# to the right. Then copy paste your `Sub` into the left box.

Comment: All that stuff is just `txtLog.BeginInvoke(()=> txtLog.AppendText(Message + Environment.NewLine));` and nothing else. You also don't risk a deadlock. just an exception in case `txtLog` has been disposed in the meanwhile

Answer (score -1):

This is the code converted to `C#`:

```
private void Log(string Message)
{
    try
    {
        if (txtLog.InvokeRequired == true)
        {
            txtLog.Invoke(() =>
            {
                Log(Message);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            txtLog.AppendText(Message + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```